# How do you access http headers when making ajax requests with Promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, bluebird

I am resolve jquery ajax requests using bluebird.js, and it is surprisingly difficult to access the http headers of my request.

Sample Code :

```
Promise.resolve($.get(...)).then(function(data){    
    //wtb http headers
});
```

I am trying to get access to the http headers returned with my response. Doing this on just an ajax request is simple, I assume someone smarter than me has figured this out already for promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this, is just to keep a reference to the jqXHR object around, so you can access it later:

```
var jqXHR = $.get(...);

Promise.resolve( jqXHR ).then( function ( data ) { 
    var headers = jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
} );
```

Comment: I like your answer better than my own

Comment: Both answers are interesting approaches.

Answer (score 2):

One difference between jQuery promises and bluebird promises (which are [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant), is that your `then` function gets only one parameter.  If you want to retain all the information that jQuery gives you, you have to wrap it up in a single object:

```
Promise.resolve($.get(...).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
    return {
        data: data,
        status: status,
        xhr: xhr
    };
})).then(function (data) {
    // data.data has the response data
    // data.xhr contains the jqXHR object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why coerce the `jqXHR` to some other Promise when, by staying in jQuery, the jqXHR is made available to both success and error handlers as a formal variable?

```
$.get(...).then(function(data, testStatus, jqXHR) {
    var headers = jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
    ...
}, function(jqXHR, testStatus, errorThrown) {
    var headers = jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
    ...
});
```

If for whatever reason you still need to coerce the jqXHR, then wrap the whole expression in `Promise.resolve(...)`. The jQuery promise returned by `.then()` is every bit as coercible as a jqXHR.